# How to apply Android 12's dynamic color according to sharedpreference's data

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I know there is a function can apply dynamic color

```
DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this)
```

But I want to manually change dynamic color according to user's choice in my APP's settings page, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dynamic color is disabled

```
recreate()
setTheme(YourTheme)//In Activity's onCreate(), should be called before setContentView()
```

If dynamic color is enabled

```
DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(this)
recreate()
```